# Error while fetching a request token using postman

Tags: magento2, token, postman

POST: http://127.0.0.1/magento/oauth/token/request

This api returns an error in response: cannot create request token because consumer token is not a verifier token.

```
oauth_problem=Cannot+create+request+token+because+consumer+token+is+not+a+verifier+token
```

Answer (score 2):

did you resolve it?

With Postman if I try oauth integration I got the same error. I've Magento 2.3.4.

Best Regards,
Francesco

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late but if someone else is facing the same issue then this would probably help:

Check and remove an entry for the consumer id in oauth_token table.

Ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2540#issuecomment-230092278